# How to filter array if one element value is empty in multidimensional array - Java Script

Tags: javascript

How can i filter lines where Name value is empty in multi dimensional array.

In the following array IDs 11910008, 9980000000, 9980000010 has no name, its just a empty string so I need to filter them.

I have tried this but no luck so far;

```js
const rows = 
//    [
//      ['ID', 'Name']
//    ];

[
  [
    [
      "11300273",
      "Domestic Supplier"
    ],
    [
      "11411110",
      "Plant Business Partner"
    ],
    [
      "11910008",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "54009145",
      "Slink"
    ],
    [
      "9980000000",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "9980000010",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "JUSTINQ",
      "JUSTINQ Inc."
    ]
  ]
]
var filtered = rows.filter(row => row.join("") !== "").map(row => row.filter((cel) => cel));
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: I have made you a snippet. Please correct the JS in a [mcve]

Comment: `var filtered = rows[0].filter(row => row[1] !== "");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test it's empty like this

```
var filtered = rows[0].filter(row => row[1].trim() !== "")
```

```js
const rows = [
  [
    [
      "11300273",
      "Domestic Supplier"
    ],
    [
      "11411110",
      "Plant Business Partner"
    ],
    [
      "11910008",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "54009145",
      "Slink"
    ],
    [
      "9980000000",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "9980000010",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "JUSTINQ",
      "JUSTINQ Inc."
    ]
  ]
];
var filtered = rows[0].filter(row => row[1].trim() !== "")
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: I have updated my question.  There is a empty string for name.
[
      "9980000010",
      ""
    ]

Comment: this worked for me rows.filter(row => row[1].trim() !== "")

Comment: Why trim the string? You just need to check if it's an empty string or not?

Comment: Just to be sure. If not needed, the trim can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
let filteredArr = rows[0].filter(item => item[1] !== '');

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rule out the values having a null name, then it could be achieved via changing out the filter method with this:

```js
var filtered = rows.map(row=>row.filter(data=>data[1]!==''))
```

Fully modified code:

```js
const rows = 
//    [
//      ['ID', 'Name']
//    ];

[
  [
    [
      "11300273",
      "Domestic Supplier"
    ],
    [
      "11411110",
      "Plant Business Partner"
    ],
    [
      "11910008",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "54009145",
      "Slink"
    ],
    [
      "9980000000",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "9980000010",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "JUSTINQ",
      "JUSTINQ Inc."
    ]
  ]
]
var filtered = rows.map(row=>row.filter(data=>data[1]!==''))
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: This is overly complicated.

Comment: sir, considering it is a multidimensional array it would be required to go through every row and column, which makes it more relevant both to the question and the context.
Please guide me if I am missing anything here.

Comment: In this specific case, this is enough in my opinion `rows[0].filter(row => row[1].trim() !== "")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use find to check if any empty string is found inside your array:

```js
const rows = 
//    [
//      ['ID', 'Name']
//    ];

[
  [
    [
      "11300273",
      "Domestic Supplier"
    ],
    [
      "11411110",
      "Plant Business Partner"
    ],
    [
      "11910008",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "54009145",
      "Slink"
    ],
    [
      "9980000000",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "9980000010",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "JUSTINQ",
      "JUSTINQ Inc."
    ]
  ]
]
var filtered = rows[0].filter((entry) => {
  // Check if we can find any empty string
  let result = entry.find((value) => { return !value.length})
  // if we found it, we filter it out
  return typeof result !== 'string'
}) 

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what's provided, try:

```
const filtered = rows[0].filter(row => row[1] !== "");
```

In this updated code, the filter() method is used on rows[0] (the nested array within the main array) to iterate over each inner array. The row[1] access the second element of each inner array, which corresponds to the Name value. If the Name value is not an empty string, the inner array is included in the filtered result.

You've been given the answer in a comment already...

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since you posted 7 answers today, most or all of which appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.